# I want to create search feature in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I wrote this code to my search feature in as3 but it is not good work
because when I click on my button module, the search results are wrong. Please look at my code when I write (123456789123).  My module trace is correct and when write (1234567899) my module trace is correct again?
How can I correct this problem?

my code pic is here:
[please click to see my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDO2R.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Instead of **rar** links... Why don't you just show your search function here? You surely must have something like `doSearch ("12345", txt_String );` so now show us what your `doSearch` equivalent function looks like.

Comment: ok dear you right but i visit this site for first and i do not know how to put my code on this site therefor i have to create link to showing my code for people!!please help me where dose my cod is wrong!!! please

Comment: Read **[How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. We can't see your code. No need for **rar** links. Why d/load it, decompress to extract file, now open file... why? just to see code text you could show here in first place? To add code you must click **[edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37512447/edit)** and see where there is a **B** and **_I_** etc? Use the **{ }** for converting pasted text to code (paste, highlight text and press the `{ }` icon)...

Comment: PS: Don't paste entire code for entire project. You problem is your search function so show that code only + any neccessary information to test it.

Comment: dear i put my code pic in my question ! i hope that useful for you to help me!!! more more thanks for your attention!

Comment: http://kirill-poletaev.blogspot.com/2010/08/searching-text-in-string-using-as3-way.html?m=1.   I think this will get you going in the right direction.

Comment: It would be easier if you pasted the code text (not image). Then we can copy/paste into our own computers for testing and fixing. Never mind.. So I typed my own code and I cannot re-produce your problem. If i make `txt3 = "123456789123";` and also have `text2.text = "1234567899";` then when I check using`text2.text.search(txt3)` I get a result of `-1` which means **match not found**. I don't know why it says **correct** for you, especially since you use a `correct only if bigger than 1` which means you expect a correct only if the **3rd letter onwards** matches your word

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `txt3` string is not empty (minimum length is `1`). 
If the `txt3` length is zero it will cause problems when you check.

You want your **Check** function to look something like this :

```
function check ( evt : MouseEvent) : void
{
    trace ("txt3 length is  : " + txt3.length); //# if zero you get bad output later
    trace ("txt3 text is    : " + txt3);

    if (txt2.length < 12)
    { trace ("Please Complete Every Space"); }

    if ( txt3.length > 0 && txt2.text.search(txt3) >= 0)
    {
        trace ("correct");
    }
    else 
    {
        trace ("wrong");
        if ( txt3.length < 1 ) { trace ("txt3 is empty String"); }
        if ( txt2.text.search(txt3) == -1 ) { trace ("txt2 VS txt3 = match was not found"); }

    }

}
```